# How to correctly sign jar in Java FX 2?

Tags: jar, sign

Basically Oracle states that the self-contained applications ( which I want to use ) will run in a sandbox environment and will not have access to OS file system, clipboard, etc unless you sign the jar. The code from their samples is:

```
<fx:signjar keyStore="${basedir}/sample.jks" destdir="dist"
alias="javafx" storePass="****" keyPass="****">
    <fileset dir='dist/*.jar'/>
</fx:signjar>
```

But this does signing only for main jar I think. I also have some libraries in dist/lib folderso I'm using this code to add them to my main jar:

```
<fx:resources>
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
</fx:resources>
```

Do I have to add another fileset to the fx:signjar, in order to sign them too or it is enough to sign the main jar only?

Regards,
Aurelian

Comment: I don't think you need to sign a jar for a self-contained application, can you provide a reference to the Oracle doc stating this.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello, yes, http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_overview.htm#CEGJGHDA . "Self-contained and web applications are, by default, run in a restricted environment, known as a sandbox." Thanks

Comment: aureliangtx, I'd like to upvote your question (because it was useful in a couple of ways), but the system won't let me until you perform a minor edit on it.

Comment: Hello, thanks,I've did a minor edit ( added a newline ).

Comment: +1, thanks for the question and assistance aureliangtx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to sign your app, sign all of your jars, not just the main jar.

For browser embedded or webstart type deployments which need to operate outside of their respective sandboxes, you can sign just one jar and not sign others, but that will result in confusing [mixed code warning dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html) for the end user and is not at all recommended.

For example the following fileset will include all of your distribution jars for signing:

```
<fileset dir='dist' includes='**/*.jar'/>
```

Jars do not need to be signed for self-contained applications to access privileged resources as they do not run within a sandbox by default.

Some application platforms (such as the OS X Gatekeeper) may benefit from signing of the self-contained application using a [platform specific tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html).  But such signing is outside the scope of the JavaFX 2.2.3 packaging tools.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out jewelsea. I've tried myself to deploy a native deb. Although I didn't sign any jar I was able to access the OS file system (I created and wrote to some file ) and also accessed the clipboard. Maybe I understood wrong, but aren't the self contained applications the native ones who run a private copy of JRE? And,as I posted upper in the link, they stated that "Self-contained and web applications are, by default, run in a restricted environment, known as a sandbox." Anyway, now I know that If I have to sign, I have to sign all my jars. Have a nice evening :)

Answer (score 3):

The deployment guide is incorrect. From an engineer on the Oracle Java deployment team: "Self-contained applications are the same as any standalone java application (e.g java -jar helloworld.jar) - it runs with no security manager by default and has all permission to do anything, just like any other native application." I have filed a Jira ticket against the deployment guide at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27483 so you can track it, and thanks to John Smith for alerting us to this error. I apologize for the time this has cost you.
Nancy Hildebrandt, 
Technical Writer,
Oracle

Comment: Hello Nancy. The thing is I was a bit fuzzy about this matter, but I've managed to solved it. Also, thank you for apologizing, this says a lot about Oracle employees :). Have a nice day